# GDB/LLDB break at all functions of specified module/shared library

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, gdb, lldb

In `lldb`, I got `help breakpoint set`:

```
       -a <address-expression> ( --address <address-expression> )
        Set the breakpoint at the specified address.  If the address maps uniquely to a particular binary, then the address will be converted to a "file" address, so that the
        breakpoint will track that binary+offset no matter where the binary eventually loads.  Alternately, if you also specify the module - with the -s option - then the
        address will be treated as a file address in that module, and resolved accordingly.  Again, this will allow lldb to track that offset on subsequent reloads.  The
        module need not have been loaded at the time you specify this breakpoint, and will get resolved when the module is loaded.
```

and

```
       -r <regular-expression> ( --func-regex <regular-expression> )
        Set the breakpoint by function name, evaluating a regular-expression to find the function name(s).
```

and

```
   -s <shlib-name> ( --shlib <shlib-name> )
        Set the breakpoint only in this shared library.  Can repeat this option multiple times to specify multiple shared libraries.
```

Now I want to set breakpoints at every function of specified module/dylib that you can find in the results of command `image list -f`.

Take `libobjc.A.dylib` and `MyOwn.dylib` as examples. I tried following commands but failed:

```
(lldb) breakpoint set -r libobjc.A.dylib
Breakpoint 1: no locations (pending).
WARNING:  Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations.

(lldb) b +[ThunderManager load]
Breakpoint 2: where = MyOwn.dylib`+[ThunderManager load] +16 at ThunderManager.m:20, address = 0x000000010489f274

(lldb) breakpoint set -r MyOwn.dylib`*
Breakpoint 3: no locations (pending).
WARNING:  Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations.
```

I want `lldb` get break at all functions of module `libobjc.A.dylib` or `MyOwn.dylib`, or any other specified loaded module/shared library. How to set the breakpoints in `lldb`?

Comment: sidenote - if you change your search to a single function, I like this command: `(lldb) breakpoint set -F access -s libsystem_kernel.dylib`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
(lldb) break set -r . -s libobjc.A.dylib
```

The `-s` option takes a shared library as its value, and that limits the breakpoint to the specified shared library.  You can specify the `-s` option more than once to specify more than one shared library for inclusion in the breakpoint search.

The `-r` option's value is a regular expression; if the symbol name matches that expression, it will be included in the breakpoint.  `.` matches everything.

The lldb tutorial:

http://lldb.llvm.org/tutorial.html

starts with a description of the structure of lldb commands that you might find helpful.